# Entity Framework 4 Delete call not working

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-4

I'm trying to delete a record from my table using EF, and nothing is happening.  The code executes with no errors, but the record just sticks around in the DB.  I have nearly identical code elsewhere that's working.

```
                using (var DB = new PTNWebConfigurationModel.PTNWebConfigurationEntities())
                {
                    var account = DB.Accounts.Where(a => a.LoginID == loginID).FirstOrDefault();


                        //Load existing session for the Account, otherwise create a new one.
                        if (!LoadExistingSession(ip, DB, account))
                        {
                            CreateNewSession(ip, DB, account);
                        }
                        AccountsSession sessionsToDelete = DB.AccountsSessions.Where(a => a.RemoteIP == ip && a.AccountID == 1).FirstOrDefault();
                        if (sessionsToDelete != null)
                        {
                            DB.DeleteObject(sessionsToDelete);
                            DB.SaveChanges();
                        }
                 }
```

I've also tried it with these options:

```
DB.DeleteObject(sessionsToDelete);
DB.SaveChanges(System.Data.Objects.SaveOptions.DetectChangesBeforeSave);
DB.AcceptAllChanges();
```

I also started with no using block and just and instantiated entity object, but that didn't work either.

Comment: You don't have an enclosing TransactionScope that you're not completing, right?

Comment: You could try the trial of http://efprof.com/

Comment: @Klaus: I fear we have this sort of thing all over the place. We're new to this. Can you describe what you mean?  We try to enclose all our transaction in using blocks, but that's all we do to try and manage the scope.

Comment: I'm referring to if you have something like `using(var txScope = new TransactionScope())` and you forget to call `txScope.Complete()`. Code like this wraps every method call inside the `using` block in a transaction, and if you don't call `Complete` changes will be rolled back.

Comment: We don't have any TransactionScope blocks.  I'm wondering if we need them. I just read about a bug with EF and SqlServer less than 2008 where the auto-open and auto-close connection piece doesn't work properly.

Answer (score 1):

I love issues like this.

Most of the times that I have seen an ORM not execute a command (and without error) is due to changes to the underlying data tables that aren't represented in the generated classes for that table.

You might refresh your schema / class model and try again.

Comment: Good tip, and I'll keep it in mind.  But it didn't work for this particular case.  Still stumped.

Answer (score 0):

Carrying on from [Chris' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4628511/entity-framework-4-delete-call-not-working/4628546#4628546) the other thing I've found in the past is if you are doing EF database first modelling then you may have created the foreign keys linking two associated tables but the key hasn't been set as delete cascade in the relationship. This can cause EF to be a little difficult. So check any FKs in your db. Hope that helps.